# How to use UART with Python?

Tags: python, uart

I am trying to work on Raspberry Pi UART in Python on Raspbian Jessie with Pixel. I followed procedures of UART settings available over internet.
These are the following links:

1. https://electrosome.com/uart-raspberry-pi-python/
2. http://programmingadvent.blogspot.in/2012/12/raspberry-pi-uart-with-pyserial.html

None of the settings seems working. The `ttyAMA0` file is not present in /dev folder. 
I have some questions:

1. Can I use `tty1` for UART? How does it work?
2. Where is the `serial.py` file saved?

Comment: What model Pi? Why are you looking at these links - at least one of which is 4 years old (I haven't bothered) when there lots of information on this site?

Answer (score 1):

The question regarding setting up a UART connection using a Raspberry Pi 3 has been answered [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/54871).

Assuming that serial.py is a python package providing access to the serial communication ports of the raspberry (e.g. you start your script with `import serial`):

Python packages can be found in `/usr/lib/python###/dist-packages/` where ### is the version number of the python you use (e.g. python2.7 or python3.4). However, normally it souldn't be necessary to change any of those files, although it can be quite helpful to look inside them in order to get an idea of how they work (and why your code own code might not be working).